# Deserializing component array using JSON

Tags: java, libgdx, component-based, serialization, json

I have a collection of serialized components in JSON format:

```
{
    "components": [{
        "class": "com.package.component.PositionComponent",
        "x": 100,
        "y": 100
    }, {
        "class": "com.package.component.VelocityComponent",
        "x": 4,
        "y": 2
    }]
}
```

I want to load this into a collection of base Components in Java, specifically into an Entity. I am currently using YAML (parsed using SnakeYAML) to achieve this. The following file (which is virtually identical to the JSON one) is parsed and the components are stored in an ArrayList:

```
components:
- ==: com.package.component.PositionComponent
  x: 100
  y: 100
- ==: com.package.component.VelocityComponent
  x: 4
  y: 2
```

Is there any way I can achieve this using the JSON parsing facilities provided by LibGDX? I am currently using the following code to parse the components, but I have no idea how to get it to construct the correct appropriate object for each component:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader();
JsonValue base = reader.parse("components.json");

for (JsonValue component : base.get("components")) {
    System.out.println(component.getString("class"));
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use a map/dictionary from component name to a function/delegate/etc that creates the desired type of component (basically a factory?

Comment: I'm more or less wondering if there is an equivalent to SnakeYAML's method of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

So are you asking how to create a class given a class type as a string?

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader();
JsonValue base = reader.parse("components.json");

for (JsonValue component : base.get("components")) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(component.getString("class"));
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
    Object object = ctor.newInstance();
}
```

Though I assume you probably have no arg consructors, if you need to pass arguments to a constructor, it is done like this (if the argument was a String):

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

Comment: Which is appropriate for deserializing JSON into _known_ objects. It won't work, however, if I want to deserialize an array of components to be stored in a collection such as `ArrayList<? extends Component>`, such that I don't know the exact type of component I am deserializing.

Comment: My bad. I updated my answer with attempt #2

Comment: Also `object` can be declared of type `Entity`, instead of `Object`, as the OP specified.